# Annotated timeline google graph displaying issue

Tags: google-visualization, annotatedtimeline

I am  displaying data on annotated timeline google chart. It displays the data fine but if I scroll down my browser page and then scroll back up, it cuts off the top part of the chart and won't display it until I hover my mouse over it. Here are the pictures of what it looks like before and after

**Before**
[image: Before]

**After**
[image: After]

How can I fix this issue? (Seriously google chart API sucks)